# Page Up keyboard shortcut in a JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, jmenuitem

I have a JMenuItem:

```
JMenuItem menuItemNext = new JMenuItem("Next");
```

How can I change this so it can be activated by the Page Up keyboard button?

Also if you could explain how I could make a keyboard shortcut for another JMenuItem that uses ctrl + [right arrow] that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
JMenuItem menuItemNext = new JMenuItem("Next");
menuItemNext.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_UP, 0));
```

For the another item:

```
menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 
     ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
```

There is two right arrows:

- **`KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT`**, Constant for the numeric keypad right arrow key.
- **`KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT`**, Constant for the non-numpad right arrow key.

See more in [*How to Use Key Bindings (The Java Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Using Other Swing Features)*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

Comment: Thats great thanks, can you update to show me how to do ctrl + arrow key aswell please?